# How to replace an existing iframe instead of appending it to the document body?

Tags: iframe, appendchild

While rendering `iframes`, I use the code:

```
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.style.width = "100%";
ifrm.style.height = 600+"px";
function makeFrame() {
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

However, this keeps appending `iframes` below the existing one, each time I call the function `makeFrame()`. So, if I call `makeFrame()` (say thrice), then I get three `iframes` one below the previous. How to prevent this and replace the existing one instead of appending to the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer:

If you want to change your code as little as possible, and you're certain that you'll only have exactly one iframe on the page at any given time

```
function makeFrame() {
oldiframe = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0] 
// getElementsByTagName will return an array (a list). 
// Adding [0] will return the first (and, under our assumptions, only) element
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.style.width = "100%";
ifrm.style.height = 600+"px";
document.body.replaceChild(ifrm, oldiframe);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean using replaceChild instead of appendChild?? I tried using that code you provided but it doesn't create any iframe?? Am I missing something?? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, your problem has to do with [variable scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)). The tl;dr of it is your function doesn't know about your oldiframe and ifrm. The problem is solved if you move everything inside of makeFrame. I've edited my original answer to reflect this.

Comment: Quick FYI: if you want to set the url of the new iframe's contents you can use, for example, `ifrm.setAttribute("src","blue.html");` You should be aware that if you try to put external sites in iframes (e.g. `src="http://www.google.com"`) you may run into trouble. The external server may have safeguards in place to prevent you (for reasons of user security / ad revenue / bandwidth).

Comment: Hi @mike, thanks a ton for the reply. That code of yours helped a lot and you can see the final working code as I put it down in the answer section.
Also, thanks for the warning against iframes. Do you know of any better way/technology to render content from external websites without any issues? Can there be any copyright issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div . Let's say div id is iframecontainer
so your code should be like:

```
<div id="iframecontainer">
<!-- Iframe goes here -->

</div>
```

Now simply getElementById with javascript and set the innerHTML to "" before appending the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mikemxm I was finally able to solve the problem. The final code looks like this:

```
oldiframe = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0]; 
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.style.width = "100%";
ifrm.style.height = 600+"px";
function makeFrame() {
   if(oldiframe == null)
     document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
   else
     document.body.replaceChild(ifrm, oldiframe);
}
```

And thanks for the warning against iframes. Do you know of any better way/technology to render content from external websites? Can there be any copyright issues? Thanks.